# Changing date format from "Jun 02, 2022 at 05:55 AM CDT" to "06/02/2022 at 05:55 AM"

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to change a date format from **"Jun 02, 2022 at 05:55 AM CDT" to "06/02/2022 at 05:55 AM"**. I tried many date conversions, but I am not getting the result I want.

```js
order.messageSentOn = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(dbDate);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Change where? Is it a variable you're trying to convert?

Comment: Can you share the code you tried ?

Comment: Thank you. I am getting first date from an api response. So I need to convert that json date to second date format like 06/02/2022 at 05:55 AM to display in table.

Comment: Code updated in question. thank you

Comment: If you want a custom format, there is no predefined method. Convert to a `Date`, then use `getDay`, `getMonth` etc to format the date. Or find a suitable library to do it for you.

Comment: .forEach loop doesnot return any value, use .map and return keyword

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: There must be thousands of questions on how to [parse a string to a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+parse+string+to+date) and [how to format a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date). Do a search, write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install moment

```
yarn add moment
// Or
npm i moment
```

Uses

```
import moment from "moment"

// ......

const date= "Jun 02, 2022 at 05:55 AM";

const formatedDate = moment(date).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A")
```

Your code

```
const tempData= data.map((order) => {
          order.messageSentOn = moment(order.messageSentOn).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm A");
    return order;
        });
        setDocumentsTable(tempData);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't do what the OP wants. "*Use library X*" is rarely a useful answer. If it was, then there would be list of  answers here with every ECMAScript date library available (there are a lot).